# How can I make a modification to a .service and keep it persistent?

Tags: systemd

I have a Debian stretch where I'm running `transmission-daemon` as a service.

I keep my seeded files on an external USB hard disk drive mounted on `/mnt/external-disk`. This disk has an `ext4` filesystem, and I mapped it in `/etc/fstab` by uuid.

The problem is:

When the service `transmission-daemon` starts at boot it doesn't check if the external filesystem is already mounted so it doesn't find the files on it, and I get a data error and the torrent files are not seeded, but the service starts.

To resolve this problem I checked the `systemd` documentation, and I found what was missing:

The line `RequiresMountsFor=` in the `[Unit]` section of the `transmission-daemon.service` file is located in the tree below `/lib/systemd/`.
After I added that line with the path of the mountpoint `/mnt/external-disk` the problem disappeared and the service was working fine.
If I rebooted the machine, the service was working, and the files were seeded.

This worked until I had a `apt-get dist-upgrade` where the package `transmission-daemon` was involved and after it stopped.
So I checked the `transmission-daemon.service`, and I found the modification I made was missing.

I added the line `RequiresMountsFor=` another time with the proper path, and the problem was fixed again.

My question is: How can I make this modification persistent?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should override the unit with a unit in `/etc`. The easiest way to do this is to use `systemctl edit`:

```
sudo systemctl edit transmission-daemon
```

will open an editor and allow you to create an override snippet.

An override snippet ensures that future changes to the package’s unit (in `/lib`) are taken into account: the reference will be the package’s unit, with your overrides applied on top. All you need to use this in your case is a `.conf` file in `/etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service.d/`, containing only the section and the `RequiresMountsFor` line. `systemctl edit` will do this for you, creating an `override.conf` file in the appropriate location.

Alternatively, you can copy the full `/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service` unit to `/etc/systemd/system` and edit that. Again, `systemctl edit` can take care of this for you, with the `--full` option.

Look for “Example 2. Overriding vendor settings” in the [`systemd.unit` documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) for details.

Answer (score 4):

Copy it to `/etc/systemd` (or an appropriate sub-directory of `/etc/systemd`) and modify the copy.

`/lib/systemd` is for packaged unit files.  They will get overwritten when systemd (or whatever package provides them) is upgraded.

`/etc/systemd` is for your own and for customised unit files.  Unit files you place in here will override the package-provided file and will not be replaced on upgrade.

Comment: Don't do that. If the service file changes in a package upgrade the copy will override those changes. Use an override file per [Stephen Kitt's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418821/26300).