# Systemd does not seem to be generating the Main PID properly

Tags: systemd, systemctl, snmp

I modified the /lib/systemd/system/snmpd.service file as needed.
Below is the contents of the snmpd.service file that I modified.

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon.
After=network.target
ConditionPathExists=/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

[Service]
Type=notify
RuntimeDirectory=agentx
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After daemon-reload, I entered the command "systemctl start snmpd".
And I got the error below.

```
× snmpd.service - Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon.
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snmpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Thu 2023-03-16 11:39:21 KST; 12min ago
    Process: 3046725 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 3046725 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 48ms

Mar 16 11:39:21 esm-dev systemd[1]: Starting Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon....
Mar 16 11:39:21 esm-dev snmpd[3046725]: Turning on AgentX master support.
Mar 16 11:39:21 esm-dev snmpd[3046727]: NET-SNMP version 5.9.1
Mar 16 11:39:21 esm-dev systemd[1]: snmpd.service: Got notification message from PID 3046727, but reception only permitted for main PID which is currently not known
Mar 16 11:39:21 esm-dev snmpd[3046727]: Received TERM or STOP signal...  shutting down...
Mar 16 11:39:21 esm-dev systemd[1]: snmpd.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Mar 16 11:39:21 esm-dev systemd[1]: Failed to start Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon..
```

According to the error, it seems that the main PID and the PID that delivered the notification message are different.

Main PID: 3046725

Got notification message from PID 3046727

...

and
The /run/snmpd.pid file contained 3046727

One interesting thing is that the difference between the MainPID and the PID that delivered the notification message is always 2.

When I entered systemctl start snmpd again,

```
× snmpd.service - Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon.
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snmpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Thu 2023-03-16 11:58:30 KST; 2s ago
    Process: 3047690 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 3047690 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 41ms

Mar 16 11:58:30 esm-dev systemd[1]: Starting Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon....
Mar 16 11:58:30 esm-dev snmpd[3047690]: Turning on AgentX master support.
Mar 16 11:58:30 esm-dev snmpd[3047692]: NET-SNMP version 5.9.1
Mar 16 11:58:30 esm-dev snmpd[3047692]: Received TERM or STOP signal...  shutting down...
Mar 16 11:58:30 esm-dev systemd[1]: snmpd.service: Got notification message from PID 3047692, but reception only permitted for main PID which is currently not known
Mar 16 11:58:30 esm-dev systemd[1]: snmpd.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Mar 16 11:58:30 esm-dev systemd[1]: Failed to start Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon..
```

MainPID: 3047690

Got notification message from PID 3047692

I wonder why MainPID and notification message from PID are different. And I wonder how to run snmpd normally with systemctl.

anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You removed the `-f` flag from the `snmpd` command line; that flag instructs `snmpd` *not* to fork. You need to restore the flag if you want your service to work properly.

Incidentally, instead of modifying `/lib/systemd/system/snmpd.service`, you should make your changes as an override:

```
sudo systemctl edit snmpd
```

See [How can I make a modification to a .service and keep it persistent?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/418820/86440) for details.